# How to put an array into a div

Tags: javascript

I want to put this array into a div so i can position it on our site. How can i do that? Or is there another way instead of putting it in a div.

```
var chair = new Array() 
{
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.id = "button" + i;
    button.innerHTML = (i > 3 && i < 8) ? "Button" : "hi";
    document.body.appendChild(button);
  }
}

document.getElementById("zaal1").innerHTML = chair;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you share your code as a fiddle?

Comment: You should add the buttons to a document fragment and append that to the body instead of appending each button to the DOM individually.

Comment: Your code does not produce any html to assign to innerHTML.. instead it actually creates some 'button' objects and appends these to the DOM

Comment: You're creating an empty array, then doing nothing with it. The following block has *nothing* to do with `chair`. It's just a block of code.

Answer (score 0):

From what i could understand, you're trying to insert some buttons in an array and then want to append them to a div in order to display them in a document, the following code does that:

```js
var chair = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.id = "button" + i;
    button.innerHTML = (i > 3 && i < 8) ? "Button" : "hi";
    chair[i] = button;
    document.getElementById("zaal1").appendChild(chair[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id = "zaal1"></div>
```

But i don't think you need an array, you can simply do:

```
document.getElementById("zaal1").appendChild(button);
```

inside the loop and that'll append 11 buttons into div as well.

Notice how i used the function `appendChild` which will keep on appending each button in the div. What you were doing `document.getElementById("zaal1").innerHTML = chair;` is wrong as your array is empty, even with filled up array, the above line will print this:

```
[object HTMLButtonElement],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object HTMLButtonElement]
```

as the array contains 11 button objects. you need to specifically append each of them to the div.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the version that uses a document fragment. Is this what you wanted to do?

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.id = "button" + i;
  button.innerHTML = (i > 3 && i < 8) ? "Button" : "hi";
  frag.appendChild(button);
}

document.getElementById("zaal1").appendChild(frag);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9zr57et/4/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned above in the comments, you should not appendChild in the DOM in a loop, nor use innerHTML in a loop :

```
if (document.createDocumentFragment) { // Use documentFragment if available
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.id = "button" + i;
        button.innerHTML = (i > 3 && i < 8) ? "Button" : "hi";
        docFrag.appendChild(button);
    }
    document.getElementById("zaal1").appendChild(docFrag);
} else {
    var zaal1, html = '';
    zaal1 = document.getElementById("zaal1");
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
         array.push( '<button id="button' + i + '">'
            + ((i > 3 && i < 8) ? "Button" : "hi")
            + "</button>");
    }
    zaal1.innerHTML = array.join(''); // Use innerHTML only when all the html is already concatenated
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmkw6kxg/1/)